# I can't figure out what kind of mobile development is a folder I have

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-build

One of my friends/clients ask me for help with his app, and he gave me access to a repository with the project folder. He told me that the app was a Phonegap app, but I can't relate the project structure with a Phonegap app.

This is the folder structure:

[image]

Can you guys help me with this? I need to compile it at least once to continue on my own.

Comment: It looks like an old cordova/phonegap app. Which version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx I'm using the latest phonegap, do I need to downgrade?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not a big developer of Phonegap, I'm just comparing that folder structure with a project of my own, maybe someone with more experience could help you

Comment: Why don't you try to create a new project and then replace that **www** folder with the newly created one

Comment: It's a phonegap app, why do you think it isn't? It's using cordova 2.9.0, see the cordova jar on libs folder.

Comment: @jcesarmobile if I run `phonegap run android` or anything like that, it tells me that I'm not in a Phonegap project

Comment: That's because it's a 2.9 project, phonegap run android will only work on phonegap 3.x.x